# ¿Por qué no se importa el paquete de Appium en Python?

Tags: python, appium

al realizar `from appium import webdriver` en Python obtengo lo siguiente:

```
from appium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appium'
```

He validado que tengo el cliente de appium instalado, no sé que puede estar pasando

```
PS C:\Python> pip show Appium-Python-Client
Name: Appium-Python-Client
Version: 3.1.1
Summary: Python client for Appium
Home-page: http://appium.io/
Author: Isaac Murchie
Author-email: isaac@saucelabs.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: selenium
Required-by:
```

Tengo Python 3.8.8 y Selenium 4.16.0, por lo que no tendría que tener problemas segun la documentación: https://pypi.org/project/Appium-Python-Client/

¿Alguien sabe a que puede deberse?

Comment: Hola Antonio, bienvenido a [es.so]. El 99% de estos errores se debe a estar usando un interprete distinto para ejecutar el script que el que tiene el paquete instalado. Asegurate de instalar el paquete en la misma version de Python o entono virtual usado luego para ejecutar tu proyecto, puedes ver la ruta del interprete usado para ejecutar el script ejecutando la linea `import sys;print(sys.executable)` al principio del mismo. ¿Estas usando jupyter/ipython?